# Is this a good pattern for PATCH

Tags: rest, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am implementing a REST style API that allows an object to be `PATCH`'ed.  The intention of the `PATCH` operation is to allow one or more properties in a class to be updated without touching an of the other properties that may be set.

The are examples of partial updates on the [ServiceStack OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#update)  page, but it seems to need hardcoding to indicate which fields will be partially updated.  In my scenario it is upto the depend application to decide which fields to send.

I also have to cope with the scenario that the object may not have been persisted yet.

To get around this I have implemented the following:

```cs
public object Patch(Myclass request)
{
    HttpStatusCode SuccessCode;
    try
    {
        var result = (MyClass)Get(request);
        if (result != null)
        {
            request.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(result);
            dbFactory.Run(dbCmd => dbCmd.UpdateNonDefaults(request, r => r.myId == request.myId));
        }
        else
        {
            dbFactory.Run(dbCmd => dbCmd.Save(request));
        }

        SuccessCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error(e);
        SuccessCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    }
    return new HttpResult()
    {
        StatusCode = SuccessCode
    };
}
```

It works, but something doesn't feel right, I'm sure there must be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks ok although you're code will be a lot shorter if you just throw let it throw C# Exceptions when there's an error and if you're inheriting from [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) base [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs) class you can use the already available `Db` property, e.g:

```
public object Patch(Myclass request)
{

    var result = (MyClass)Get(request);
    if (result != null)
    {
        request.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(result);
        Db.UpdateNonDefaults(request, r => r.myId == request.myId);
    }
    else
    {
        Db.Save(request);
    }

    return new HttpResult
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mythz, I hadn't noticed Db was already there for me!  Would that be a good candidate as an extension to ORMLite, so I could just call Db.Patch(request)?

Comment: You can use `db.UpdateNonDefaults` or you could just have a separate partial DTO (e.g. `[Alias("MyClass")] UpdateMyClass { ... }`) with only the properties you want updated and just call `db.Update(request)`.

Comment: The problem I have is I am allowing Patch to update any one or more properties on the DTO and it's upto the app/user depending on what they are changing.

Comment: I may have misunderstood db.UpdateNonDefaults.  Off to write some tests!